# calculate percentage difference - python

Tags: python, list

I am calculating the percentage difference between two values in a list.

```
#cal percentage dff: (val2/val)/100
values = [0.11889, 0.07485, 0.01070, 0.03076, 0.01606]
values = [int(round(i*100)) for i in values]

conversion_values = []
for x in range(1, len(values), 1):
    val_1 = values[x-1]
    if val_1 == 0.0: #Check if val_1 is 0.
        conversion_values.append('-')
    else:
        val_2 = values[x]
        diff = (val_2/val_1)*100
        conversion_values.append(diff)

conversion_values

output:
[0, 0, 300, 0]
```

Desired output:

```
   [58, 14, 300, 67]
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here? In Excel this calculation works fine but not here, must be something to do with the decimal points??

Note - this is not a question about percentage change, that's a different thing altogether.

Comment: To add to the other commenters - in Python 3.x, `/` is a floating point division operator regardless of divisors. But in Python 2.x, which you're using, `/` is integer division if rhs and lhs are both integer. Hence, the flooring effect that you're seeing.

Comment: You can also remove the "int" in the second line and then deal with it when you're adding to the list at the end:  conversion_values.append(int(round(diff)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loosing precision when performing `(val_2)/val_1` so convert either one of them to float to get the end result as floats and then convert the result to int

```
values = [0.11889, 0.07485, 0.01070, 0.03076, 0.01606]
values = [int(round(i*100)) for i in values]

conversion_values = []
for x in range(1, len(values), 1):
    val_1 = values[x-1]
    if val_1 == 0.0: #Check if val_1 is 0.
        conversion_values.append('-')
    else:
        val_2 = values[x]
        diff = int(round((float(val_2)/val_1)*100)) # change to float -->round--> int
        conversion_values.append(diff)

conversion_values
```

Output:

```
[58, 14, 300, 67]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it does what I want!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using integer division. 
Please rewrite this

```
diff = (val_2/val_1)*100
```

to this

```
diff = (val_2/float(val_1))*100
```

or even to this

```
diff = (val_2/(val_1 * 1.0))*100
```

Comment: Thanks man, had to give it to 'mad_' because he just beat you to it. But thanks again!